# Why does git rebase --onto over here only pick up 2 commits instead of 5?

Tags: git

I'm solving exercises over here: https://gitexercises.fracz.com/committer/vd7

[image]

We need to add commits H and I to your-master.

This is supposed to be the solution:

```
git rebase --onto your-master issue-555 rebase-complex
```

We're basically telling git to pick up all commits between issue-555 and rebase-complex branches and place them into your-master, isn't it?

Then this should have picked up G, F, E, H, and I in that order and placed them on top of D.

Why does this solution only pick up H and I but ignores E, F, and G?

Comment: I've been using Git for years and always thought `rebase --onto` was working as OP thought as well. No need to be agressive @matt ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We're basically telling git to pick up all commits between issue-555 and rebase-complex branches and place them into your-master, isn't it?

No, we're telling Git to pick up all commits

- that are reachable from `rebase-complex`
- *except those* that are reachable from `issue-555`.

Keep in mind that a commit is "reachable" only by walking in the direction of the arrows in your graph, not in the opposite direction.

You can think of it as a set operation:

- Take the set {A, B, E, H, I}
- and subtract from it the set {A, B, E, F, G}.

Answer (score 1):

Upon reading the question, my solution would have been:

```
git rebase --onto your-master E rebase-complex
```

because `E` is the parent of the first commit we want to begin with (`H`). It's important to realize that you can replace `E` with `F` or `G` (or `issue-555`) and get the same result. One way to conceptualize this is if you were to do a regular rebase (without `--onto`) of `rebase-complex`, the same 2 commits would get "re-played" regardless of whether you did `git rebase E` or `git rebase F` or `git rebase G`. (But of course the results would certainly be different because of different starting points.)

For fun, you can easily prove this with a Git Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -v

# create the original graph
git init
git branch -m your-master
echo A > A.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit A"
echo B > B.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit B"
git branch issue-555
echo C > C.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit C"
echo D > D.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit D"
git switch issue-555
echo E > E.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit E" && git tag tag-E
git branch rebase-complex
echo F > F.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit F" && git tag tag-F
echo G > G.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit G" && git tag tag-G
git switch rebase-complex
echo H > H.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit H"
echo I > I.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit I" && git tag tag-I

# show the current graph
git log --all --graph --oneline

# rebase onto E
git rebase --onto your-master tag-E rebase-complex
git log --all --graph --oneline

# reset back to starting point (tag-I)
git reset --hard tag-I

# rebase onto F
git rebase --onto your-master tag-F rebase-complex
git log --all --graph --oneline

# reset back to starting point (tag-I)
git reset --hard tag-I

# rebase onto G which is the same commit as issue-555
git rebase --onto your-master tag-G rebase-complex
git log --all --graph --oneline
```

The script first creates the graph in question, and then tests rebasing onto `E`, `F`, and `G` separately, by resetting back to the starting position in between each rebase command. The output is the the same graph in all 3 cases. Note tags are used simply as place holders for the original commit ID of `rebase-complex`, and for the 3 commits in question. (They actually aren't needed since I could have used `issue-555~X` and even reflog index entries, but the tags are clearer in the graph.) Due to the tags and the use of the `--all` flag to `git log`, you will be able to see commits `H` and `I` twice in the graph.

**Interesting Side Note:** when I ran this script, not only were the resulting graphs after the 3 rebases the same, but the re-written commits of `H` and `I` also had the same pair of *commit IDs* all 3 times. Quiz: Why would that be?

The reason is:

> The resolution of a timestamp in Git is 1 second. My script ran fast enough that all 3 rebases occurred within the same second on my computer clock, so the commits all literally had the same inputs for the hash. On subsequent attempts only 2 out of 3 sets of commits were identical, as the second boundary was crossed. If you add a `sleep 1` command between rebases you could guarantee different commit IDs.

Here's the example output of my last run:

```
#!/bin/bash -v

git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Code/TestRepo/.git/
git branch -m your-master
echo A > A.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit A"
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in A.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
[your-master (root-commit) 12477b2] Commit A
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 A.txt
echo B > B.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit B"
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in B.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
[your-master 832a0d8] Commit B
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 B.txt
git branch issue-555
echo C > C.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit C"
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in B.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in C.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
[your-master 0bd0ad7] Commit C
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 C.txt
echo D > D.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit D"
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in B.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in C.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in D.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
[your-master e285cf6] Commit D
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 D.txt
git switch issue-555
Switched to branch 'issue-555'
echo E > E.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit E" && git tag tag-E
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in B.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in E.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
[issue-555 a7d37b2] Commit E
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 E.txt
git branch rebase-complex
echo F > F.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit F" && git tag tag-F
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in F.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
[issue-555 c64a6c4] Commit F
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 F.txt
echo G > G.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit G" && git tag tag-G
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in F.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in G.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
[issue-555 244a4ab] Commit G
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 G.txt
git switch rebase-complex
Switched to branch 'rebase-complex'
echo H > H.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit H"
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in H.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
[rebase-complex ca9d230] Commit H
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 H.txt
echo I > I.txt && git add . && git commit -m "Commit I" && git tag tag-I
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in H.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in I.txt.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
[rebase-complex a2efe08] Commit I
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 I.txt

# show the current graph
git log --all --graph --oneline
* 244a4ab (tag: tag-G, issue-555) Commit G
* c64a6c4 (tag: tag-F) Commit F
| * a2efe08 (HEAD -> rebase-complex, tag: tag-I) Commit I
| * ca9d230 Commit H
|/
* a7d37b2 (tag: tag-E) Commit E
| * e285cf6 (your-master) Commit D
| * 0bd0ad7 Commit C
|/
* 832a0d8 Commit B
* 12477b2 Commit A

# rebase onto E
git rebase --onto your-master tag-E rebase-complex
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/rebase-complex.
git log --all --graph --oneline
* 4d20994 (HEAD -> rebase-complex) Commit I
* f655e84 Commit H
* e285cf6 (your-master) Commit D
* 0bd0ad7 Commit C
| * 244a4ab (tag: tag-G, issue-555) Commit G
| * c64a6c4 (tag: tag-F) Commit F
| | * a2efe08 (tag: tag-I) Commit I
| | * ca9d230 Commit H
| |/
| * a7d37b2 (tag: tag-E) Commit E
|/
* 832a0d8 Commit B
* 12477b2 Commit A

# reset back to starting point (tag-I)
git reset --hard tag-I
HEAD is now at a2efe08 Commit I

# rebase onto F
git rebase --onto your-master tag-F rebase-complex
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/rebase-complex.
git log --all --graph --oneline
* 4d20994 (HEAD -> rebase-complex) Commit I
* f655e84 Commit H
* e285cf6 (your-master) Commit D
* 0bd0ad7 Commit C
| * 244a4ab (tag: tag-G, issue-555) Commit G
| * c64a6c4 (tag: tag-F) Commit F
| | * a2efe08 (tag: tag-I) Commit I
| | * ca9d230 Commit H
| |/
| * a7d37b2 (tag: tag-E) Commit E
|/
* 832a0d8 Commit B
* 12477b2 Commit A

# reset back to starting point (tag-I)
git reset --hard tag-I
HEAD is now at a2efe08 Commit I

# rebase onto G which is the same commit issue-555
git rebase --onto your-master tag-G rebase-complex
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/rebase-complex.
git log --all --graph --oneline
* 7c76496 (HEAD -> rebase-complex) Commit I
* 85dbe65 Commit H
* e285cf6 (your-master) Commit D
* 0bd0ad7 Commit C
| * 244a4ab (tag: tag-G, issue-555) Commit G
| * c64a6c4 (tag: tag-F) Commit F
| | * a2efe08 (tag: tag-I) Commit I
| | * ca9d230 Commit H
| |/
| * a7d37b2 (tag: tag-E) Commit E
|/
* 832a0d8 Commit B
* 12477b2 Commit A
```

In that run 2 out of 3 of the rebases had the same pair of commit IDs.

Answer (score 0):

> pick up all commits between issue-555 and rebase-complex branches

No. There are no commits "between" those two things.

A commit is just the name of one commit. It happens that issue-555 is G, and rebase-complex is I. There is nothing "between" those.

Also rebasing does not move or "pick up" any commits. You cannot move a commit or alter a commit in any way. Rebasing *copies* commits.

Now think about *reachability* thru the parent chain. The expression `issue-555 rebase-complex` means: Work your way back along the parent chain starting at I until you come to a commit whose parent is also reachable from G. Those are the commits to copy.

Well, that's H, because its parent E is reachable from G. So we copy everything from H thru I.